# Javascript close an tab you just opened

Tags: javascript, url

I want to open a URL in a new window, and after x seconds or when the page is done loading I want to close it again.

I am now using:

```
window.open('http://otherurl.com', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;
```

The 'otherurl' is not domain, so I cannot control that URL.

How can I do this?

Comment: window.close() to close the tab

Comment: @JordanHendrix That is to close the current tab? I want to close the new tab I just opend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`window.open` gives you a reference to that window, so:

```
var newWindow = window.open('http://otherurl.com', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250');

setTimeout(function() { newWindow.close(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Is there also a possible way to close it when it is fully loaded?

Comment: I don't see how you'd be able to do that without some coordination with the other site, for security purposes. You can't read or write from a window looking at a different domain.

Comment: @MatthewDotcom, although you can't know when the external page is fully loaded, you could compensate by adding extra time to the setTimeout function.